# C# Generic interface and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a generic interface which inherits from another generic interface from a third party library (which makes it impossible to use covariance and contravariance) .

Here is my code

```
public interface IFABaseAppService<TDto, TKey> 
         : ICrudAppService<TDto, TKey> where TDto : FABaseDto
{
}
```

I have another interface `IUserAppService`

```
public interface IUserAppService : IFABaseAppService<UserDto, Guid>
{
}
```

Then I have a base class which accepts `IFABaseAppService<FABaseDto, Guid>` in constructor as a parameter

```
public class FABaseStandardFormViewModel : FABaseViewModel
{
    public FABaseStandardFormViewModel(IFABaseAppService<FABaseDto, Guid> appService) : base(appService)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I have created a class which accepts `IUserAppService` in the constructor and passes it to the base class, but it is giving me the following error:

> cannot convert from 'FinancialsAce.ApplicationServices.Common.IUserAppService' to 'FinancialsAce.ApplicationServices.IFABaseAppService<FinancialsAce.DataTransferObjects.FABaseDto, System.Guid>

Answer (score 1):

This error message means that IFABaseAppService<UserDto, Guid> can not be converted to IFABaseAppService<FABaseDto, Guid> because IFABaseAppService is not declared as covariant relatively to TDto.

See more about covariance: [Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/).

You can fix it by adding **out** keyword as shown below:

```
public interface IFABaseAppService<out TDto, TKey> ...
```

Comment: Sir as i mentioned in my question i can't use covariance and contravariance because my interface is inherited from another generic interface from a third party library. when i add out it doesn't let me pass it to other interface,